# Can't run programs as administrator from Windows GUI

Tags: windows-11

I have an up to date Windows 11 Dell laptop that I personally own (no corporate mgmt). I recently (don't know how recently) noticed that I can't run any program as admin from the Windows GUI (start menu or right-clicking) - but I can from Task Manager.  Specifically:

- I *can* run as admin by starting Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc), then File menu: run new task, click on "create task w/ admin privileges".  For instance, I can start CMD and delete a file that needs admin rights.
- I *can not* run as admin via the Windows GUI.  E.g. I right-click on a Desktop shortcut to CMD, click "Run as admin" (yes, it's in the menu), and the program doesn't start - no window opens, no error msg or dialog box.  The menu disappears, so the GUI realizes I clicked, and if I click on other items like Properties that works.
- I also *can not* run as admin via the Start Menu.  E.g. Ctrl + Esc (search start menu), type cmd, the app comes up, and there is a menu on the right that has "run as admin" as an item.  I click on it, and *nothing happens* - as if I didn't click.  Or, I can right-click on the CMD icon that appears in the start menu, select "run as admin", and like when I right click on a Desktop shortcut the menu goes away but nothing happens.

I followed the advice of music2myear using DISM.exe and SFC.exe, to no effect.

Comment: Are you saying that when you right-click on programs in the Start Menu you do not see the Run as Administrator? Which programs? Some programs cannot be run as administrator, I believe, and knowing which program(s) you're having problem will help us better understand the issue.

Comment: Thanks.  Say I type Ctrl-Esc and then cmd (to search for cmd = DOS prompt).  Command Prompt is found, and there's a panel to the right with 2nd item "Run ad admin."  Or, I can right-click on "Command Prompt" and "Run as admin" is the first item.  So not problem getting "run as admin" - the problem is clicking either of them does nothing!  Nothing at all, click as much as I want nothing happens.  I can click other items and they work fine.

Comment: Try DISM and SFC and restart and see if that fixes it. No issue on 3 Windows 11 Pro machines here (2 Production and 1 Insider). (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: OK thanks for the detailed info, I followed it exactly, restarted, no luck, same problem as before.  Jeez.  Perhaps my user profile is somehow messed up and needs to be re-initialized?  I am OK doing this, as long as I don't lose any "real" (non-user-profile) files in my home dir.

Comment: Please add any edits we request to the question itself. The question is your primary focus right now, and making sure it has all the information it needs in order to be answered.

Comment: Now, what it seems you're saying is that you CAN run things as administrator, but the programs don't "open", or show on the screen when you do? Also, going on about "very poor design" and discussing your frustrations with Microsoft do not improve your question: focus on the question. Your computer MAY be misbehaving, and it is likely NOT Microsoft's fault.

Comment: OK I re-wrote the question, looking forward to any further advice.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> when you double click on the app to open it.

Comment: Nope, app just opens in normal, non-admin mode.

Comment: Does it work with the Microsoft Built-in local administrator account?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how to use that.  I did some googling and things looked complicated enough that I'll ask for more advice here instead of playing with it myself.

Comment: @Mastaxx - Your question makes no mention of the use of the built-in Administrator account

Comment: Inside computer management fo to "local Users and groups" > Users. Now right click the administrator account and "set password". Now right click the administrator account and click properties. Untick the box that says "this account is disabled". Now sign out of the machine and sign in as administrator using the password you set. Try running programs as admin through there. Does it work through there?